# How to remove all rows matching a criteria in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a simple email management system using Google Sheets, Forms and Apps Scripts, but I'm new to Javascript/Google Apps Script and I've been stuck on this problem for quite a bit now.

So, I have a spreadsheet with contacts, listing their name, email and group, that looks like this:

```
| Name  | Email             | Group  |
|-------|-------------------|--------|
| John  | john@example.com  | A      |
| Bill  | bill@example.com  | A      |
| Janet | janet@example.com | B      |
| Mary  | mary@example.com  | B      |
| Mary  | mary@example.com  | Delete |
| Bill  | bill@example.com  | Delete |
| Janet | janet@example.com | A      |
```

I am trying to write a script that programmatically finds all emails that are marked with "Delete" and removes all rows containing those emails. In this case, I would need to eliminate all rows containing mary@example.com and 
bill@example.com and keep John and Janet. Expected output:

```
| Name  | Email             | Group  |
|-------|-------------------|--------|
| John  | john@example.com  | A      |
| Janet | janet@example.com | B      |
| Janet | janet@example.com | A      |
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to filter my sheet in this way and my script keeps copying everything, including the rows I would like to remove. This is the code I wrote so far:

```
function removeDelRows() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Gets active sheet
    var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get values in active sheet

    var toDelete = new Array();
    var newData = new Array();

    // Put in toDelete array all emails marked as "Delete"
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][2] == "Delete") {
            toDelete.push(data[i][1]);
        }
    }
    // !BUGGY!
    // Find all rows that contains emails to be deleted and remove them 
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < toDelete.length; k++) {
            if(data[j][1] == toDelete[k]){} // Do nothing
            else{
                newData.push(data[j]); // THIS CONDITION IS NOT BEHAVING AS EXPECTED; NEWDATA IS A COPY OF DATA
            }
        }
    }
  Logger.log(newData); // newData should contains only rows that do not match toDelete ones

  // Delete everything else
    sheet.clearContents();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData); 
}
```

I'm sure the solution is quite trivial, but I've been banging my head for hours and hours and I cannot figure out this!

Answer (score 2):

How about using deleteRow()?

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Gets active sheet
    var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get values in active sheet

    nextLine: for( var i = data.length-1; i >=0; i-- ) { 
      if( data[i][2] !== "Delete" ) continue nextLine;
      ss.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I've modified your version a little bit and now it works perfectly!

Comment: dont forget to mark it as answered since it's working. click the gray checkmark

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution involves an api call for every row that will be deleted. This might not be the best solution if you have a sheet with 10's of thousands of records.